# Javascript Object property value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, properties

I did some search but I always find how to access the value of an object that is an array, or something like that.

What I want to achieve is to pass values from an array to my object property value.

Let me show you my actual code for better understanding.

```
//the array i want to use in my object
var grades = [3, 7, 6, 16, 8, 2, 12, 5, 19, 12, 8, 2, 15, 12, 17, 16, 4, 19, 9, 11, 18, 1, 15, 19, 8]

//My rectangle prototype. Some values are changed using the createRectangle() function.
var rectangle = {
        x: Parameters[2], // this is the center of the rectangle
        y: 0,
        dx: 0, // delta x and y are the movement per frame
        dy: 0,
        w: 70, // size
        h: 55,
        color: "yellow",
        text: null,
        textColor: "black",
        cutX: Parameters[2],  //X position of cut mark (same as rectangle)
        cutY: 700,
        dxCut: 0,
        dyCut: 0,
        cutWidth: 75,
        cutHeight: 30,
        cutColor: "#ffffcc",
        cutStroke: "purple",
        strokeHeight: 5,
        draw() { // function to draw this rectangle
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x - this.w / 2, this.y - this.h / 2, this.w, this.h);
            ctx.fillStyle = this.textColor;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
            ctx.fillStyle = this.cutColor;
            ctx.fillRect(this.cutX - this.cutWidth / 2, this.cutY - this.cutHeight / 2, this.cutWidth, this.cutHeight);
            ctx.fillStyle = this.cutStroke;
            ctx.fillRect(this.cutX - this.cutWidth / 2, this.cutY - 8 / 2, this.cutWidth, this.strokeHeight);
        },
        update() { // moves the rectangle
            this.x += this.dx; //x = x + dx  (do we need to update the position ? )
            this.y += this.dy;
            this.cutX += this.dxCut;
            this.cutY += this.dyCut;
        }
    };


//function to create rectangle object
function createRectangle(settings) {
            return Object.assign({}, rectangle, settings);
    }


// function to store rectangles in object array and then spawn rectangle
 function spawnRectangle() {
          if (spawnCountdown) {
              spawnCountdown -= 1;
          } else {
              rectangles.push(
                    createRectangle({
                        y: canvas.height / 1.5,
                        text: function findGrade() {
                                for (var i=0; i<grades.length; i++) {
                                    return this.grades[i];
                                }
                            }, 
                        dx: 2, 
                        dxCut: 2,
                        cutY: randPosition(),
                    })
                );
                spawnCountdown = spawnRate;
            }
    }
```

So if I explain a bit, in my whole code I have a function that loop through an array to see how many rectangles to create. Then, each time, a rectangle is created using the function `spawnRectangle()` and push this rectangle to an array of objects.

What I want to do is that each rectangle created from the `spawnRectangle()` function have its own text property value from my `grades`array.

Note that I printed out my `grades` array here, but in the actual code, this array is generated from a server-side code (and all those values are updated by ajax).

Comment: has it ever worked? what is `rectangle` or `settings`?

Comment: The `for` loop in your `createRectangle` function is useless as it returns from the very first iteration (so does another `for` loop later in your code).

Comment: Why `return` from `for` loop?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, it worked, but printed out my whole array at first and then only the index 0. I just edited my question with the part of code about `rectangle`. And `settings` is the parameter from the `createRectangle` function. It's actually the properties values that I'm passing inside `rectangles.push(createRectangle({ }); `

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Ok, then what would be the easiest way to achieve what I want? For now, I'm just trying to pass my `grades` array values to `rectangle` when iterating or creating new rectangles object but with the next array index value.

Comment: dont you get any errors? should'nt you change `draw()...` and `update()...` to `draw: function(...` and `update: function(...` ?

Comment: @GeomanYabes No, don't get errors. I juste pasted here a part of my code because my code is pretty long and my question has nothing to do with any of that... Just passing array values in my object property. But the answer from guest271314 is working.

Comment: oh sorry.. haven't seen they are function declarations.. missed the *`{`* and *`}`* haha..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `Object.assign()` from `createRectangle()` and use `rectangles` array `.length` to reference index for `grades` array

```
function createRectangle(settings) {
  return Object.assign({}, rectangle, settings);
}
```

```
rectangles.push(
  createRectangle({
    y: canvas.height / 1.5,
    text: grades[rectangles.length]
    dx: 2, 
    dxCut: 2,
    cutY: randPosition()      
  })
)
```

Comment: Oh. I'm so numb... Too simple... I understand now. thanks !